# LabelEncoder order of fit for a Pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I am fitting a scikit-learn [LabelEncoder](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html#sklearn-preprocessing-labelencoder) on a column in a pandas [df](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html).

How is the order, in which the encountered strings are mapped to the integers, determined? Is it deterministic?

More importantly, can I specify this order?

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import preprocessing

df = pd.DataFrame(data=["first", "second", "third", "fourth"], columns=['x'])
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
le.fit(df['x'])
print list(le.classes_)
### this prints ['first', 'fourth', 'second', 'third']
encoded = le.transform(["first", "second", "third", "fourth"]) 
print encoded
### this prints [0 2 3 1]
```

I would expect `le.classes_` to be `["first", "second", "third", "fourth"]` and then `encoded` to be `[0 1 2 3`], since this is the order in which the strings appear in the column. Can this be done?

Comment: To have the resulting encoding ordered, see [`OrderedLabelEncoder `](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62802281/9698684)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's done in sort order. In the case of strings, it is done in alphabetic order. There's no documentation for this, but looking at the source code for [LabelEncoder.transform](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/51a765a/sklearn/preprocessing/label.py#L130) we can see the work is mostly delegated to the function [numpy.setdiff1d](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html), with the following documentation:

> Find the set difference of two arrays.
>
> Return the **sorted**, unique values in ar1 that are not in ar2.

(Emphasis mine).

Note that since this is not documented, it is probably implementation defined and can be changed between versions. It could be that just the version I looked use the sort order, and other versions of scikit-learn may change this behavior (by not using numpy.setdiff1d).

Comment: At least for the current version it is clear how it is done, and it behaves deterministic.

Comment: @tkja But I would rather not rely on this. If it is important for your application, might as well implement the encoding yourself. If you rely on it and it ever changes, it will be a very hard to track bug.

Answer (score 6):

I was also a bit surprised that I cannot provide an order to `LabelEncoder`. A one line solution can be like this:

```
df['col1_num'] = df['col1'].apply(lambda x: ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth'].index(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to specify the order of the LabelEncoder for one of my applications. Since I didn't want to migrate some code and use some other libraries. I managed to implement a temporal workaround for this.

Since at the beginning I know the categories in the dataset, I created dummy categories that would be sorted alphabetically to the specific order I wanted. Example

```
{
0:ARejected,
1:ZApproved
}
```

After that I fitted the label encoder on the dataset. Once it was fitted I replace the classes of the label encoder to ensure that in the future it mapped the labels as I wanted it.

```
le=LabelEncoder()
le.fit (X)
le.classes = np.array(['Rejected,'Approved'])
```

This might help some people in specific cases. It is definitely not a permanent solution since when fitting the encoder again information might be loosed. Or if the number of categories is too large.

Comment: The line `le.classes = np.array(['Rejected,'Approved'])` helped me to solve an issue I had when I experienced a `TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index` when trying to use `le.inverse_transform()`.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be changing the **classes_** attribute of the label encoder.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
le = LabelEncoder()
le.fit(["first", "second", "third", "fourth"])
le.classes_ = np.array(["first", "second", "third", "fourth"])
le.transform(["first", "second", "third", "fourth"])
```

The code above set the labels in the same order as le.classes_ and its output is:

```
array([0, 1, 2, 3])
```

Answer (score 1):

Seven years already, but I needed it just now.
So you'll find a one-line solution similar to Ezra's way:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import preprocessing
df = pd.DataFrame(data=["first", "second", "third", "fourth"], columns=['x'])
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()

# ONE LINE SOLUTION, approach similar to Ezra's, but without fitting the encoder
le.classes_ = df['x']   # after this line I got the desired result

print list(le.classes_)
### this prints ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth']

encoded = le.transform(["first", "second", "third", "fourth"]) 
print(encoded)
### this prints [0 1 2 3 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use `OrdinalEncoder` from `category_encoders` package. It has a *mapping* parameter where you can set the conversion you want for each category. You can read more about it in the [documentation](https://contrib.scikit-learn.org/category_encoders/ordinal.html).

Here you are an implementation example:

```
from category_encoders import OrdinalEncoder

# Ascending order according to value counts
keys = df.columnName.value_counts().sort_values(ascending=False).index
values = list(range(len(keys))) # do np.array()+1 in case you want it to start with 1
mapping = [{
    'col': 'columnName',
    'mapping': dict(zip(keys, values))
}]
oe = OrdinalEncoder(cols=['columnName'], mapping=mapping)
df.columnName = oe.fit_transform(df).columnName # Read note
```

Note: I recommend applying the encoding this way since the encoder can cause problems changing the dtype of other columns.