# Preserve order when label encoding

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn, data-science

When label encoding numbers

```
[1, 1, 2, 6]
```

`LabelEncoder` return `[0,0,1,2]` because it sorts the classes

What's the best possible way to get `[1,1,0,2]` by preserving the original order

Tried - `CategoricalIndex`, which works the same way

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
le.fit([2, 1, 2, 6])

# le.classes_ [1,2,6]

le.transform([1, 1, 2, 6])
```

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38749305/labelencoder-order-of-fit-for-a-pandas-df

Comment: Did go through that. Didn't find any elegant solution, only reasoning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can using `factorize`

```
pd.factorize([2, 1, 2, 6])[0]
array([0, 1, 0, 2])
```

Comment: This is a good way to do fit_transform. Can this be used to transform another list?

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it. Wonder if there any existing functions in pandas that can do this.

```
refdict=dict()
for i,j in data.Hash.items():
    if j in refdict:
        refdict[j].append(i)
    else:
        refdict[j]=[i]
for i in refdict:
    refdict[i]=min(refdict[i])
data.Hash.apply(lambda x:refdict[x])
```

Answer (score 0):

I have customized the [`LabelEncoder`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7813f7efb/sklearn/preprocessing/label.py) to use uniques without sorting. Try [my wrapper on LabelEncoder](https://gist.github.com/venkyyuvy/b5484dc3e2e77c86d8360f1e4ed7159f)!

```
>>> le = CustLabelEncoder(preserve_order=True)

>>> le.fit([2, 1, 2, 6])
>>> le.classes_
# array([2, 1, 6])

>>> le.transform([2, 1, 2, 6]) 
# array([0, 1, 0, 2])

>>> le.inverse_transform([0, 1, 0, 2])
# array([2, 1, 2, 6])
```

```
>>> le = CustLabelEncoder(preserve_order=False)

>>> le.fit([2, 1, 2, 6])
>>> le.classes_
# array([1, 2, 6])

>>> le.transform([2, 1, 2, 6]) 
# array([1, 0, 1, 2])

>>> le.inverse_transform([0, 1, 0, 2])
# array([1, 2, 1, 6])
```