# LabelEncoder with ordered encoding

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn

I am using label encoder

```
data = [[1,'A'],
        [1,'A'],
        [1,'B'],
        [2,'C']]

le = LabelEncoder()
df = pd.DataFrame(data = data,columns = ['id','element'])
df['element'] = le.fit_transform(df['element'])
```

output

```
   id  element
0   1        0
1   2        0
2   3        1
3   4        2
```

Which is fine but if I have lot of data than the sequence gets mashed up something like this

```
   id  element
0   1       1
1   2       1
2   3       2
3   4       0
```

Any solution without label encoder which makes sure the sequence is maintained

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**: For a simple approach there's `pd.factorize`. Though for an approach with the usual scikit-learn `fit`/`transform` methods [`OrderedLabelEncoder`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62802281/9698684) is defined, which simply overrides two of the base class' methods to obtain an encoding where codes are ordered by order of appearance of the classes.

---

The classes in `object` dtype columns get sorted lexicographically in [`LabelEncoder`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html), which causes the resulting codes to appear unordered. This can be seen in [`_encode_python`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/fd237278e895b42abe8d8d09105cbb82dc2cbba7/sklearn/preprocessing/_label.py#L58), which is called in it's [`fit`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/fd237278e895b42abe8d8d09105cbb82dc2cbba7/sklearn/preprocessing/_label.py#L175) method. In it, when the column `dtype` is `object` the `classes` variable (then used to map the values) are defined by taking a `set`. A clear example, could be (replicates what is done in `_encode_python`):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,'C'],[1,'C'],[1,'B'],[2,'A']], columns=['id','element'])
values = df.element.to_numpy()
# array(['C', 'C', 'B', 'A'], dtype=object)
uniques = sorted(set(values))
uniques = np.array(uniques, dtype=values.dtype)
table = {val: i for i, val in enumerate(uniques)}
print(table)
{'A': 0, 'B': 1, 'C': 2}
```

The resulting `set` is used to define a lookup table which will determine the order of the features.

Hence, in this case we'd get:

```
ole = LabelEncoder()
ole.fit_transform(df.element)
# array([2, 2, 1, 0])
```

---

For a simple alternative, you have [`pd.factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html), which will mantain sequencial order:

```
df['element'] = pd.factorize(df.element)[0]
```

Though if you need a class with the usual scikit-learn `fit`/`transform` methods, we could redefine the specific function that defines the classes, and come up with an equivalent that maintains the order of appearance. A simple approach, could be to set the column values as dictionary keys (which maintain insertion order for Pythons >3.7) with `uniques = list(dict.fromkeys(values))`:

```
def ordered_encode_python(values, uniques=None, encode=False):
    # only used in _encode below, see docstring there for details
    if uniques is None:
        uniques = list(dict.fromkeys(values))
        uniques = np.array(uniques, dtype=values.dtype)
    if encode:
        table = {val: i for i, val in enumerate(uniques)}
        try:
            encoded = np.array([table[v] for v in values])
        except KeyError as e:
            raise ValueError("y contains previously unseen labels: %s"
                             % str(e))
        return uniques, encoded
    else:
        return uniques
```

Then we could inherit from `LabelEncoder` and define `OrderedLabelEncoder` as:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.utils.validation import column_or_1d

class OrderedLabelEncoder(LabelEncoder):
    def fit(self, y):
        y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)
        self.classes_ = ordered_encode_python(y)
    def fit_transform(self, y):
        y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)
        self.classes_, y = ordered_encode_python(y, encode=True)
        return y
```

One could then proceed just as with the `LabelEncoder`, for instance:

```
ole = OrderedLabelEncoder()
ole.fit(df.element)
ole.classes_
# array(['C', 'B', 'A'], dtype=object)
ole.transform(df.element)
# array([0, 0, 1, 2])
ole.inverse_transform(np.array([0, 0, 1, 2]))
# array(['C', 'C', 'B', 'A'], dtype=object)
```

Or we could call `fit_transform` too:

```
ole.fit_transform(df.element)
# array([0, 0, 1, 2])
```