# Python: Change values in pd.DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe, and one of the columns cotains categorical data which I want to change to numbers

```
le=LabelEncoder()
for col in p3data.columns.values:
    if p3data[col].dtypes=='object':
        p3data[col]=le.fit_transform(p3data[col])
```

When I use this code on one of my columns in my pandas dataframe it changes the values

Very Low = 4

Low = 1

Medium = 2

High = 0

Very High = 3

However this is not in order, how can i change them manually so that it is in order i.e

Very Low = 0

Low = 1

Medium = 2

High = 3

Very High = 4

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62802049/labelencoder-with-ordered-encoding/62802281#62802281) maybe?

Answer (score 0):

You could define your preferred mapping as a dictionary and pass it to pd.rename:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html

After that you can still convert the type of the column to int: `p3data[col].astype(int)`

Answer (score 0):

Try `.replace`:

```py
values = [
    "Very Low",
    "Low",
    "Medium",
    "High",
    "Very High"
]
replace_map = {v: k for k, v in enumerate(values)} 

for col in p3data.columns:
    if p3data[col].dtypes == 'object':
        p3data[col] = p3data[col].replace(replace_map)
```