# label encoding for categorical values with specific order and customization

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, encoding

I have a dataframe `df` like this:

```
Student_id         Subject           Performance_level
10010              mathematics        Satisfactory 
10011              Physics            Poor
10012              Chemistry          Neutral
10013              Physics            Poor
10014              History            Neutral
```

I want to use **label encoding** the column `Performance_level` with `Poor` as `1` and `Neutral` as `2` and `Satisfied` as `3`(i.e, order or ranking is important)
By default label encoding sorts according to Alphabetic order and assign corresponding Numerical value. How to customize this to the specific values like  `Poor` as `1` and `Neutral` as `2` and `Satisfied` as `3`.

```
Student_id         Subject           Performance_level   Performance_level_encoded
10010              mathematics        Satisfactory               3
10011              Physics            Poor                       1
10012              Chemistry          Neutral                    2
10013              Physics            Poor                       1
10014              History            Neutral                    2
```

Comment: I think you need dictionary and then use `map`

Comment: But whether `mapping`  be considered as ordinal encoding, whether ML model will recognize the order for those categorical feature?

Comment: Ya, not sure if possible in label encoding, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38749305/labelencoder-order-of-fit-for-a-pandas-df?noredirect=1&lq=1)